# Why views is not shown in mobile browser

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mobile-web, views

I asked a question on stackoverflow from mobile. There was no response on that question for quite a lomg time, so I wanted to check if question is being viewed or not. And to my surprise I could not see views anywhere on the page.
Any reason this functionality being missed out?

Comment: For some reason they think it is not important. However you can click the full site link and see the number of views.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101008/mobile-site-can-we-see-views-somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easy reason to leave it out is the lack of space for all features and metrics on SO.

You could convert your question in a feature request, so the SE team can pick it up if it is deemed useful.

For now, click `full site` in the footer of the mobile site and you will see the full site, including views.